# Newline not being replaced in regex match?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code attempting to parse lines starting with # and replacing each line with a an empty string, however the newline is not getting stripped:

-- input --

```
# Remove this.
# remove this
# remove this line
keep # this line
keep this # line too
```

-- actual output (the . represents blank line) --

```
.   
.
.
keep # this line
keep this # line too
```

-- expected output

```
keep # this line
keep this # line too
```

-- code --

```
    String text = "# Remove this.\n# remove this\n# remove this line\n" +
        "keep # this line\nkeep this # line too";
    System.out.println(text);
    Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^#(.*)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()) {
        text = m.replaceAll("").replaceAll("[\n]+$", "");
        System.out.println(text);
    }
```

How can I remove the \n's in the regex match?

Comment: @helderdarocha Put that as an answer. Seems to work for me at least.

Comment: Can `# remove` be at last line? I am asking since there probably will be no `\n` so `^#.*[\n]` will not be able to match.

Comment: @Pshemo, yes it could...great observation, this should cover that use case: "^#.*[\n]?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `^#.*[\n]` to select the lines including the newline character.

Comment: Actually, one thing -- is the character class for `\n` necessary?